# Project references break after adding a nuget import project (".targets") file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, nuget

We have a project that requires a pre-build task - signing a DLL without source code. For this, we're using Brutal Dev StrongNameSigner, which works well.

Recently, we've added this package from nuget - this adds an entry in the csproj such as the following:

```
<Import Project="..\packages\Brutal.Dev.StrongNameSigner.2.1.3\build\Brutal.Dev.StrongNameSigner.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Brutal.Dev.StrongNameSigner.2.1.3\build\Brutal.Dev.StrongNameSigner.targets')" />
```

That line picks up information such as environment variables needed for compilation. Unfortunately, that line also breaks all our project references, such as below:

[image: Broken References in Visual Studio]

I've checked their properties; it's all empty.
[image: No properties]

Removing the Import line will cause all of the DLLs to show up correctly, but fail to build due to missing environment variables.

Oddly enough, it seems that the project still builds!

Comment: What is your project type? Do you mean when you add the package `Brutal.Dev.StrongNameSigner` to your project break the reference? Have you do any other operation? I have installed some of packages (not all) in your picture, `Microsoft.Sharepoint` and `Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.Administration`, then install  the package `Brutal.Dev.StrongNameSigner`, but not got the same issue as you. So could please provide some steps or a sample to reproduce this issue?